# Timestamp : Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, tensor, python-datetime

I have pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
time                                value
2019-05-24 04:15:35.742000+00:00    -0.085714
```

At one point of my code when I try to do this:

```
hist = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train, 
...
)
```

where X_train is derived from the dataframe and looks like :

```
array([[[Timestamp('2019-05-21 14:16:37.091000'), -0.22857142857142856,          1.3553382233088835],
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Timestamp)
```

Edit:

```
tr['execution_time'] = pd.to_datetime(tr.execution_time).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

This also didn't help.

Comment: What is the type of X_train values ? is it <class 'datetime.datetime'> ?

Comment: Yes, the type of that particular col is ```datetime64[ns, UTC]```@KnowledgeGainer

Comment: As I can see from the example your column name is time so try this and then tell the type of col, it should get convert to datetime object   --------->            df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time).dt.tz_localize(None)

Comment: It is in datetime64[ns, UTC] object

Comment: You might be able to use `astype(int)` which converts Timestamp to nanoseconds since the epoch (Unix time)

Comment: First, is this a numpy array, or a pandas dataframe.  The display suggests pandas.  pandas has more power in converting times.  Second, what's the relation between what you show, and the `x_train`, `ytrain` that you pass `fit`?  Full traceback might help.  You might need to focus on making a valid numeric numpy array before passing it to `fit`.

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer I did that and the type was changed to datetime64[ns]. But I still see the same numpy/tensor error in the next steps

Comment: Yes initial one is pandas df. X_train is an array like this: ```array([[[Timestamp('2019-05-21 14:16:37.091000'), -0.22857142857142856,
         1.3553382233088835],``` @hpaulj

Comment: @MrFuppes please read my comment above

Comment: Apply .timestamp() on the converted value

Comment: Is it giving error ?

Comment: Yes ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'timestamp'``` @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: `import pandas`
`for i in range(len(tr)):`
  `tr['execution_time'][i]=tr['execution_time'][i].timestamp()`

Comment: I would still get the Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Timestamp) error @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: After the above step change it to float first

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost amidst all the steps since you have suggested multiple different ideas. Could you maybe draft an answer with the steps in order please? @KnowledgeGainer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232128/discussion-between-knowledgegainer-and-jbd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to convert it to **datetime** object.

```
df['execution_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.execution_time).dt.tz_localize(None)
```

After that we have to convert **datetime** object to float value using **timestamp()** function

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  df['execution_time'][i]=df['execution_time'][i].timestamp()
```

After that we can convert the values to **float**.

```
df = df.astype('float32')
```

And then it can be converted to tensors easily.